# .serialize() catch no value of contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, javascriptserializer

I have create a html contact form, and a php sender mail file. 
After, i have add a jquery code for return a confirmation message., but now the code not work because serialize function take no value.

Here my html code:

```
<div id="form" >

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Nome e Cognome"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">Messaggio</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Messaggio"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
            <button id="submit">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the same file, the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit').click(function() {
          var dati = $("#form").serialize();
          alert(dati);
         $.ajax({
               type:"post",
               url:"contact_form.php",
             //  data:  $("#form").serialize(),
                data: dati,
dataType: "html",
               success: function(response){
                   $(".returnmessage").html(response);
               }
       });
      });
   });
```

alert(dati); Always return an empty message

Where's the error? Thank's

Comment: console.log(dati)

Comment: `#form` is not a form but a div! try wrapping your form fields in a form tag and use serialize on it

Comment: two possible options are there. given in the solution

Comment: it work! thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize` method have to be called on form element - in your case it's `div`.
According to jQuery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Only form elements are examined for inputs they contain

The simplest solution is to change wrapper so instead of `<div id="form" >` use `<form id="form" >`

Answer (score 1):

you need to take a Form tag because serialize() method only work with html Form

code somthing like this

```
<form id="form" >

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">Nome</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Nome e Cognome"> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">Messaggio</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Messaggio"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <button id="submit">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: thanks, now it work but after i change #form in <form> the jquery code have stop to return message...any idea to solve that?

Comment: is function got successfully executed

Comment: yes, the function is successfully executed, but not show the message  $(".returnmessage").html(response);

Comment: what is the response value ? can you please show sever side code

Comment: in the php file i have:                                           mail("ilariaparodi2000@yahoo.it", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);
echo "Messaggio inviato.<br/>La contatteremo prima possiibile.";                     Before change <div> to <form> it was working